# XAMARIN.Android WCF Method Call Is Not Completing

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin

I have  a Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin Form that has a button on it that when clicked will execute a WCF method that returns a number.  The app works fine in UWP and the app receives the number from the WCF call.  On Android (emulator) though the method is executed but never completes.  I ran wireshark and even see in trace logs on the web server that the call is received and the data is returned to the computer running the emulator, but the app is acting like it's still waiting.  I do have Internet permission selected in the project properties for the android app.  The code is below.  You can see that there is a before and after debug log entry.  The "before update data" entry is written to the debug log, but the "past update data" entry is not.  And no errors are being thrown.  Thanks for any help.

```
      private async void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs ea)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("before update data");



        Task.Run(() => 
      UpdateData().ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext:false)); 



        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("past update data");
    }
```

**This is the debug information after I press the button.**

```
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #2
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #3
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
04-05 06:39:22.845 D/Mono    (11093): DllImport attempting to load: '__Internal'.
04-05 06:39:22.845 D/Mono    (11093): DllImport loaded library '(null)'.
04-05 06:39:22.845 D/Mono    (11093): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
04-05 06:39:22.845 D/Mono    (11093): Searching for 'monodroid_get_system_property'.
04-05 06:39:22.845 D/Mono    (11093): Probing 'monodroid_get_system_property'.
04-05 06:39:22.845 D/Mono    (11093): Found as 'monodroid_get_system_property'.
04-05 06:39:22.846 D/Mono    (11093): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
04-05 06:39:22.846 D/Mono    (11093): Searching for 'monodroid_free'.
04-05 06:39:22.846 D/Mono    (11093): Probing 'monodroid_free'.
04-05 06:39:22.846 D/Mono    (11093): Found as 'monodroid_free'.
[0:] before update data
04-05 06:39:23.313 D/Mono    (11093): Image addref Mono.Security[0x86f7ce20] -> Mono.Security.dll[0x860aa200]: 2
04-05 06:39:23.313 D/Mono    (11093): Prepared to set up assembly 'Mono.Security' (Mono.Security.dll)
Loaded assembly: Mono.Security.dll [External]04-05 06:39:23.313 D/Mono    (11093): Assembly Mono.Security[0x86f7ce20] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1

04-05 06:39:23.314 D/Mono    (11093): AOT: image 'Mono.Security.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.companyname.SampleClient -1/lib/x86/libaot-Mono.Security.dll.so" not found
04-05 06:39:23.314 D/Mono    (11093): AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/Mono.Security.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.companyname.SampleClient-1/lib/x86/libaot-Mono.Security.dll.so" not found
04-05 06:39:23.314 D/Mono    (11093): Config attempting to parse: 'Mono.Security.dll.config'.
04-05 06:39:23.314 D/Mono    (11093): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.config'.
04-05 06:39:23.314 D/Mono    (11093): Assembly Ref addref System[0x874de1a0] -> Mono.Security[0x86f7ce20]: 2
04-05 06:39:23.314 D/Mono    (11093): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Security[0x86f7ce20] -> mscorlib[0x9c6e9160]: 47
04-05 06:39:23.411 D/Mono    (11093): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0x9c6e9be0] -> System[0x874de1a0]: 12
04-05 06:39:23.511 D/Mono    (11093): Image addref System.ServiceModel.Internals[0x858bf300] -> System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll[0x860a9300]: 2
04-05 06:39:23.512 D/Mono    (11093): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Internals' (System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll)
04-05 06:39:23.512 D/Mono    (11093): Assembly System.ServiceModel.Internals[0x858bf300] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
04-05 06:39:23.512 D/Mono    (11093): AOT: image 'System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.companyname.SampleClient-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll.so" not found
04-05 06:39:23.512 D/Mono    (11093): AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.companyname.SampleClient-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll.so" not found
04-05 06:39:23.512 D/Mono    (11093): Config attempting to parse: 'System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll.config'.
04-05 06:39:23.512 D/Mono    (11093): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.ServiceModel.Internals/System.ServiceModel.Internals.config'.
04-05 06:39:23.512 D/Mono    (11093): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0x874dfe20] -> System.ServiceModel.Internals[0x858bf300]: 2
04-05 06:39:23.513 D/Mono    (11093): Assembly Ref addref System.ServiceModel.Internals[0x858bf300] -> mscorlib[0x9c6e9160]: 48
Loaded assembly: System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll [External]
04-05 06:39:23.601 D/Mono    (11093): Assembly Ref addref System.ServiceModel.Internals[0x858bf300] -> System.Xml[0x874de560]: 6
04-05 06:39:23.602 D/Mono    (11093): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0x874dfe20] -> System[0x874de1a0]: 13
04-05 06:39:23.728 D/Mono    (11093): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
04-05 06:39:23.728 D/Mono    (11093): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_int_method'.
04-05 06:39:23.728 D/Mono    (11093): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_int_method'.
04-05 06:39:23.728 D/Mono    (11093): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_int_method'.
Thread started:  #6
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #7
```

Comment: Are you updating the UI from work thread?

Comment: No.  I added the debug information that occurs after I click the button.  Thanks.